# Elasticsearch.NET search records starts with a value in a string field (NEST)

Tags: string, elasticsearch, search, .net-core, nest

I have an issue for searching on elastic. I use NEST library for search and I try to get records that is `customername` field start with 'GÖKDEMİR' (for example)

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<AccountAddressInfo>(p => p 
.Query(q => q
    .MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CustomerName)
        .Query(filter.CustomerName)
        )
    ) 
.Size(101));
```

With this search, I get the record on response that contains 'GÖKDEMİR' in `customername` field but I want to get fields starts with 'GÖKDEMİR'.
How can I do this.

Comment: What is the mapping for `customerName` field?

Comment: Mapping is for property name, it configured on startup. there is no mappimg for datatype

Answer (score 0):

In case your `customername` field is a `term` type, then you can try to use just `Prefix` where you are using `MatchPhrasePrefix` like so :

```
.Query(q => q
    .Prefix(m => m
        .Field(f => f.CustomerName)
        .Query(filter.CustomerName)
        )
    ) 
.Size(101));
```